# How to pass an array variable from R to C++ in a parallel Rcpp code in a thread safe way?

Tags: r, rcpp, rcppparallel

I would like to pass an array in a parallel code with RcppParallel.

First, I can pass an array with arma::cube. Is an arma::cube variable thread safe in a parallel code?

Second, to make a NumericVector thread safe, we can convert it to `RcppParallel::RVector<double>`. To make a NumericMatrix thread safe, we can convert it to `RcppParallel::RMatrix<double>`. Is there a `RcppParallel::RArray<double>` equivalent for an arma::cube or another type of variable?

I am expecting a simple yes/no answers or short examples.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a simple look at the header file in question reveals there isn't such a data structure.  So this question is, on balance, too close to 'write code for me please'.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment! I did a research. On my end, I did not find anything. I wanted to be sure I did not miss anything. The solution I am using right now is to convert the arma::cube variable to a std::vector  variable or a RcppParallel::RVector<double> variable. I wanted to know if there was a better solution that avoids this kind of conversion.